# Execute a SQL file in Ruby on Rails to import a database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I'm a Ruby on Rails newbie and I have to:

1. Read an SQL file
2. Execute the statements in the file
3. Create one or more databases based on the SQL statements (not a specific database; this must work for any...)

Currently, I can import the file and read it. I only need to create the database from the information that I am reading.

Comment: I don't recommend using ruby.  Every RDBMS comes with a command-line tool for this exact purpose.  For example in postgres you'd use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html).  If you insist on using ruby for this, you'll need to decide on a specific RDBMS or this question will not be specific enough.

Comment: Using Ruby for this task would be sensible if you had your data not in SQL, but in JSON or maybe YAML. SQL is already native for RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

As commented above, Rails has nicer ways to do this or you can do straight through your database. However, if you must do it from Rails you can execute arbitary SQL from a migration like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(YOUR_SQL_HERE)
```

Comment: By the way, this can be done in Rails console as well, which is preferred if it's a one-time procedure. Storing a database dump with application's sources is not good practice.